# Добавить контролы на панель элементов (ToolBox)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть код

```
DTE2 inst = null;
inst = version.IdeInstance;


foreach(var c in Controls)
{
    ToolBoxTab curTab = null;
    foreach(ToolBoxTab tab in inst.ToolWindows.ToolBox.ToolBoxTabs)
    {
        if (tab.Name == c.Key)
        {
            curTab = tab;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (curTab == null)
        curTab = inst.ToolWindows.ToolBox.ToolBoxTabs.Add(c.Key);


    if (curTab != null)
    {
        curTab.Activate();
        //var curTab2 = (ToolBoxTab2)curTab;
        foreach (var c1 in c.Value)
        {


            ToolBoxItem curItem = null;
            foreach(ToolBoxItem item in curTab.ToolBoxItems)
            {
                //var item2 = (ToolBoxItem2)item;
                if (item.Name == c1.Key)
                {
                    item.Delete();
                    curItem = curTab.ToolBoxItems.Add(c1.Key, c1.Value, vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (curItem == null)
                curTab.ToolBoxItems.Add(c1.Key, c1.Value, vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);
        }
    }

}

if (!inst.UserControl)
    inst.Quit();
```

`inst` - это экземпляр студии (DTE2)

`Controls` - `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. Здесь первый стринг - это имя таба, второй стринг - имя контрола, третий стринг - Assembly контрола, вида `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`

Табы создаются, но контролы не добавляются. Что я делаю не так?